# magento change add to cart to buy now from admin panel

Tags: php, magento

I want to change magento add to cart to buy now or else from admin panel. I do not want to make changes in code 
Please guide where can I find option in admin panel.
I could not find any option in admin panel  for same. As I change any code changes will be lost on update.

Comment: No update affect your theme's template folder. it mainly affect core files. so change in template folder. Change'll not loss on Update.

Comment: what if i update theme also

Comment: Yes, That Might caught problem. I guess anz answer is perfect. but still if u update theme locale will be updated. there'll be also same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way you can achieve this is using the translate.csv , rather than changing multiple phtml files .

Go to your theme. Then inside you theme, go to Locale > en_US. Open the translate.csv using any text editor. Then add the following line the csv.

```
 "Add to Cart","Buy Now"
```

Save, clear cache from admin, and then refresh. Voila! it must be done.

Comment: thanks
but it will be replaced with defalut value when i update theme , how to avoid that

Comment: Update theme? if you create a new theme altogether, then add the same line to the translate.csv of the theme,a s it is "ONLY THEME BOUND". However, if u update magento versions, then u will be still using the same theme, so will not create any problem. If you want to permanently change that for all the theme, then you need to add a translate in the database, but I would recommend this, as it is very easy, and one changes theme once in what 1-2 years??

Comment: pls tell database way also

Comment: You need to add the phrase to "core_translate" table in the DB, and enable INLINE TRANSLATION. TO enable, go to System -> Configuration -> Developer and then find Translate inlined and set Enabled for frontend Yes. REMEMBER: if the same phrases are in DB as well as CSV, the Phrase in the DB will always take the precedence.